# .onscroll só é lido uma vez

Tags: javascript, funções, eventos

Estou tendo alguns problemas com uma função `.onscroll`:

```
window.onscroll=function(){
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop>5){
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    }else{
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.4)";
    }
}
```

No caso, quando dou o `scroll` na página, ele só lê a ação de `scroll` uma única vez, e sempre entra na condição `else`, pois começa o `scroll` em 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julgo que queres usar o `document.body` e não `documentElement`.

Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```js
var menuPrincipal = document.getElementById('menuPrincipal');
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 5) {
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    } else {
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.4)";
    }
}
```

```css
#menuPrincipal {
    height: 2000px;
    background: #eef;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuPrincipal"></div>
```

Comment: assim que liberar dou como resposta, funcionou

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop>5){
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    }else{
        menuPrincipal.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.4)";
    }
});
```